# rospack depends geometry_msgs vs rosmsg packages Header

Tags: ubuntu, std-msgs, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04 and I have some problem in understanding the consistency of the output of the following two commands:

```
$rospack depends geometry_msgs:
<nothing>
```

```
$rosmsg packages Header
...
gazebo_msgs
gazebo_plugins
geometry_msgs <--
hpPackage
...
```

So geometry_msgs is using the Header message from std_msgs, but geometry_msgs does not depend on std_msgs. One example of using the Header message is geometry_msgs/TwistStamped:

```
$rosmsg show geometry_msgs/TwistStamped
std_msgs/Header header <--
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
geometry_msgs/Twist twist
  geometry_msgs/Vector3 linear
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
  geometry_msgs/Vector3 angular
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
```

Isn't it a bug?

Best Regards,
Stephan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53333/rospack-depends-geometry_msgs-vs-rosmsg-packages-header/) by [Stopfer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4049/stopfer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS Fuerte, some of the core stacks/packages were converted to use a prototype version of the catkin buildsystem ([docs here](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/catkin/html/)). In this version, the notions of "packages" and "stacks" were re-defined (all deps were pushed to the stack level and all manifest.xml files were made to just contain other metadata). Since `common_msgs` is one of these stacks that was catkinized, neither `rospack` nor `rosstack` in Fuerte can parse this xml file. In this case, `std_msgs` gets built and installed top `/opt/ros/fuerte/include/std_msgs` (the new FHS standard), so as long as `/opt/ros/fuerte` is in a given C++ package's include path, you will be able to include C++ headers from `std_msgs` (there's a similar setup for Python). You'll see that things like dependency specification are defined differently:

ROS Diamondback ([rosbuild](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild))

- [stack.xml](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/blob/common_msgs-1.4/stack.xml): `<depend stack="ros_comm" />`
- [manifest.xml](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/tree/common_msgs-1.4/geometry_msgs/manifest.xml): `<depend package="rosbagmigration"/>` (gives you `std_msgs` via this dep)

ROS Fuerte ([catkin prototype](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/catkin/html/)):

- [stack.xml](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/blob/fuerte-devel/stack.xml): `<build_depends>std_msgs</build_depends>`, `<depends>std_msgs</depends>`
- [manifest.xml](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/blob/fuerte-devel/geometry_msgs/manifest.xml): No dependency information

ROS Groovy ([new catkin](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/catkin/html/)):

- [stack.xml](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/blob/groovy-devel/stack.xml): Gone
- [manifest.xml](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/blob/groovy-devel/geometry_msgs/manifest.xml): Gone
- [package.xml](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/blob/groovy-devel/geometry_msgs/package.xml): `<build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>`, `<run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>`

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-01-25**:
This answers all. Whole response of mine is rather pointless now.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-01-25**:
Well I did skip the version where there was such a thing as "stack.yaml" (:

**Comment by [Stopfer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4049/stopfer/) on 2013-01-25**:
Sounds like the right answer. Thank you. Its somehow disapointing, because we are developing roscs (http://ros.org/wiki/roscs), which is a wrapper for ros in order to use c# under linux. We encounter problems, if someone wants to use geometry_msgs in his c# application.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-01-25**:
@Stopfer, all is not lost. Are you using the rospack and rosstack shell scripts to get info about ROS packages? Instead, you could use the [rospkg](https://github.com/ros/rospkg) python library, which CAN parse all of these files. I'm not sure why rospack/rosstack don't, though. Maybe file a bug?

**Comment by [Stopfer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4049/stopfer/) on 2013-01-27**:
Thx, we will try it that way. So the bug would state, that rospack and rosstack are not able to parse the stack.xml and manifest.xml, correctly?

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-01-27**:
Well, at this point, I'm not sure if it will be fixed, since the issue occurs with a now-outdated prototype version of catkin, but there's no harm in posting it. Make sure you post it here: https://github.com/ros/rospack/issues

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`geometry_msgs` package contains multiple msg types (see [its wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/geometry_msgs#)). Some of them, as you cited `TwistStamped` for example, uses `std_msgs/Header` (while some others don't same as you referred). Thus as a package, it depends on `std_msgs`.

Right now I don't have an access to `fuerte` but in `groovy`,

```
$ rospack depends geometry_msgs 
cpp_common
rostime
roscpp_traits
roscpp_serialization
genmsg
genpy
message_runtime
std_msgs
```

---

Update) I confirmed on `fuerte` indeed `rospack depends geometry_msgs` returns nothing, and in its `manifest.xml` no dependency is defined. In the [history on github](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/commit/0d2de4f25e1eb277bbf4658b433c1ba4d7060661#geometry_msgs/manifest.xml) @kwc says:

```
 stripping depend and export tags from common_msgs manifests as msg dependencies are now declared in cmake and stack.yaml.
```

This explains why `geometry_msgs` can still refer to `std_msgs` w/o the dependency not being defined in `manifest`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stopfer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4049/stopfer/) on 2013-01-24**:
Where can I find this cmake and stack.yaml entry? I mean where is it said, under fuerte, that geometry_msgs needs std_msgs?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-01-24**:
Again I don't have an access to `fuerte` on filesystem but on github, https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/tree/fuerte-devel. I assume `stack.yaml` might be typo of `.xml`

**Comment by [Stopfer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4049/stopfer/) on 2013-01-24**:
The command "grep -inr "std_msgs" .", executed in /opt/ros/fuerte/share/geometry_msgs does not find any matches. So I guess, that there is no hint about a dependency to std_msgs in fuerte.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-01-24**:
`geometry_msgs` is a "package" not a `stack`. How about in `common_msgs` stack where `geometry_msgs` pkg belongs to?

**Comment by [Stopfer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4049/stopfer/) on 2013-01-24**:
"grep -inr "std_msgs" ." executed in /opt/ros/fuerte/share/common_msgs brings up: ./stack.xml:24:build_depends>std_msgs</build_depends>
./stack.xml:28: std_msgs
. But rosstack depends common_msgs does not show up std_msgs.

**Comment by [Stopfer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4049/stopfer/) on 2013-01-24**:
"grep -inr "std_msgs" ." executed in /opt/ros/fuerte/share/common_msgs brings up: